# Why won't curl download this link when a browser will?

Tags: curl

I am running Mac OS 10.11.6 El Capitan.  There is a link I would like to download programmatically:

```
https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.7/mysql-5.7.16-osx10.11-x86_64.dmg
```

If I paste this URL into any browser (e.g. Safari) the download works perfectly.

However, if I try to download the same URL from the command line using `curl`, it doesn't work—the result is an empty file:

```
$ ls -lA
$ curl -O https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.7/mysql-5.7.16-osx10.11-x86_64.dmg
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
$ ls -lA
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 myname  staff  0 Nov  7 14:07 mysql-5.7.16-osx10.11-x86_64.dmg
$
```

Of course I can get the file through the browser, but I would like to understand *why* the `curl` command above doesn't work.

**Why can't `curl` download this file correctly,** when it is evidently present on the website and can be correctly accessed and downloaded through a graphical web browser?

Comment: I'd like to point out that even though techraf's answer on redirects is completely correct, other factors such as headers may cause a server to reject the curl client's request to download a file.

For example, if the server has backend DDoS protection, such protection software commonly checks for viable browser headers, such as having a proper `User-Agent`. Additionally, some browser downloads may succeed due to session cookies (i.e if you're logged in) being only present on said browser.

Comment: To troubleshoot a curl command, you can use `curl -v` for "verbose". It will print to standard error various info about the connection, request, and response. In this case, you would see that the response includes `HTTP 302 Found` (a redirect code) and a `Location` header with the URL to go to. Then you could `man curl` to find out how to tell it to follow redirects.

Comment: I had the same problem and adding authorization header worked for me. `curl --header "Authorization: Basic 12345" -o indexexport.zip http://localhost:8080/indexexport`

Answer (score 97, accepted):

There is a redirect on the webserver-side to the following URL: `http://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/MySQL-5.7/mysql-5.7.16-osx10.11-x86_64.dmg`. Because it's a CDN, the exact behaviour (whether you get redirected or not) might depend on your location.

`curl` does not follow redirects by default. To tell it to do so, add the `-L` argument:

```
curl -L -O https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.7/mysql-5.7.16-osx10.11-x86_64.dmg
```

Comment: A HTTPS-to-HTTP redirect?  That's awful, and I'm not surprised that Curl leaves it well alone...

Comment: And if this doesn't solve it? Something to do with .asp stuff maybe?

Comment: "Because it's a CDN, the exact behaviour (whether you get redirected or not) might depend on your location.". Vaguebooking. Explain properly please. Downvoted.

Answer (score 18):

If the browser is able to download the file, you can inspect what the browser is doing. 
On google chrome you can use the following to see what’s happening.

1) **[View > Developer > Developer tools > Network Tab > Headers tab]**

2) Click on the download link.

3) The file link will appear on the developer tools tab.

4) Right click on the file and select Copy > Copy as cURL.

Now you have a curl link that will work. 
It will probably have excess parameters you can trim-away.

More details: 
https://lornajane.net/posts/2013/chrome-feature-copy-as-curl

Comment: YES! This is exactly what I needed. Maybe it's obvious, but I took the cURL command and added`--output download.csv` to the end of it, else it streams the file to stdout I think.

Comment: won't work in many cases, curl from chrome doesn't work, but the browser still render the jpeg file

Answer (score 1):

I am going to convert one of the comments on this post to an answer.

There are many HTTP/HTTPS links that require certain headers in order to work. So this will result in a working response from a web browser but not a working response in a backend web request like curl.

I just ran into a site that required all the following headers. Failure to specify them resulted in a timeout.

```
  httpget.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.62 Safari/537.36");
  httpget.setHeader("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
  httpget.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
  httpget.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
  httpget.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
  httpget.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
  httpget.setHeader("Host", "www.thehost.com");
```